# How to calculate all points for which this program won't halt and what $e$ have in common with this?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, recurrence-relations

#### Main

I was playing python and created very intresting figure:
[image]

It was done by:
$$
x_{n+1} = 1 \bmod x_{n}
$$
$$
x_0 \in [0,1)
$$
And the code is:

```
  while x != 0:
    x = 1 % x
```

I wonder if it is possible to calculate all values for which this program won't halt.
I suspect that those special values will be irrational numbers, but how to properly calculate all of them?

With using numerical approach I have approximated one of the branch:
[image]
Which is equal to:
$$
0.63212055882855767840447622983853913255418886896823... \approx \frac{e-1}{e}
$$

What is more, the slope of these straight lines (colored on red) is:
$$
(-1)^{n} n!
$$

What about the rest of the branches?
Will all of them be a combination of $e$?

---

#### Edit 1

The plot is done by:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

acc = 100_000
def func(xmin=0, xmax=1):
  px = []
  py = []
  for x in np.linspace(xmin, xmax, acc):
    x0 = x
#    px.append(x0) # <--
#    py.append(x)  # <--
    while x != 0:
      x = 1 % x
      px.append(x0)
      py.append(x)
  return px, py

px, py = func()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
l, = plt.plot(px, py, '.k', ms=1)

plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand the algorithm...how could a sequence starting from an irrational converge?  If $x_{n+1}<1$ is rational (say, $0$)  then we know that $x_{n+1}=1+kx_n$ for some $k\in \mathbb Z$ so $x_n$ is rational as well.  Or have I misread?

Comment: What I don't understand is how you determine the coordinates of the points you plot. Please give as well the other Python instructions you use for plotting.

Comment: @JeanMarie I added section "Edit 1"

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, we cannot answer questions about plots without you providing the code that generated those plots. However, it is possible to answer your first question: This program halts if and only if the initial value is rational.

---

Define a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\ge 0}$ recursively, via $x_{n+1}=1-\lfloor1/x_n\rfloor x_n$. You ask for what initial values $x_0\in [0,1)$, there does not exist an $N\ge 1$ such that $x_N=0$. This formulation is not watertight, since if such an $N$ exists, $x_{N+1}$ is not well-defined, but you get the point.

First off, $x_{n+1}$ is rational if and only if $x_n$ is rational. Therefore, if $x_0$ is rational, all the $x_n$ are rational and if $x_0$ is irrational, all the $x_n$ are irrational. Therefore, we can only get $x_N=0$ for some $N\ge 1$ if $x_0$ is rational. This is essentially lulu's comment. See if you can prove this yourself using induction.

---

Let $n\ge 1$ and suppose $x_n=a/b$ for some integers $a,b$ with $a,b\neq 0$ and $b>0$. I claim that $x_{n+1}=r/b$ for some integer $a>r\ge 0$.

Proof: Write $b=aq+r$, where $q\ge 1$ and $a>r\ge 0$ are integers, then
$$
x_{n+1} = 1-\lfloor 1/x_n\rfloor x_n = 1-\lfloor \frac{aq+r}{a}\rfloor\cdot \frac ab=1-q\cdot\frac{a}{b}=\frac{b-qa}{b}=\frac rb.
$$
We conclude that if $x_n$ is rational, there exits an $N\ge 1$ such that $x_N=0$.

Comment: Is it possible that this plot shows all rational and irrational numbers for $x \in [0, 1)$? Even those that are not yet found/used?

Comment: I wonder if there is a connection with continued fractions ?